# uncheck material checkbox after closing modal

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular-material

In an application I've a checkbox that filters a table. In that table you have a button to return a product. After closing the confirmation modal I want to uncheck the checkbox.

The ngModelChange is working well if I check/uncheck box manually.

I've tried (ngModelChange), (change), [checked]

angular version:8

HTML:

```
<mat-checkbox (ngModelChange)="changeSeeOnlyInUse()" [(ngModel)]="seeOnlyInUse">Show Only Products in use.</mat-checkbox>
<div class="table-container"> 
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

TS:

```
ngOnInit() {this.seeOnlyInUse=false;}

public returnProduct(registration) {
    //do some stuff and open modal
    modalRef.afterClosed().subscribe (response => {
        // do some stuff
        this.seeOnlyInUse = false; //<- now I want to uncheck box})
}

public changeSeeOnlyInUse(){
    this.seeOnlyProductsInUse = !this.seeOnlyProductsInUse;
    // do some stuff }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

HTML

```
<mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="seeOnlyInUse"[formControl]="checkboxFormControl">>Show Only Products in use.</mat-checkbox>
<div class="table-container"> 
    <table>
        ...
    </table>
</div>
```

TS

```
checkVCFormControl : FormControl =  new FormControl("")

....

this.checkboxFormControl.valueChanges.pipe(takeUntil(this._onDestroy)).subscribe(() => {
  // do some stuff
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#closeModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) { $('.creditCheckbox').prop('checked', false); })
```